# How to generate MBtiles using WPS process in geoserver?

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

How to generate mbtiles in geoserver? using openlayers for displaying geoserver layer

for example calling wms layer like this

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Kanpur", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {
       LAYERS: 'sample_data_old:sample',
        STYLES: '',
        format: 'image/jpeg',
        tiled: false,
        transparent: true,
        tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom,
        visibility:false
    }, { 
        isBaseLayer: true 
    }  
);
```

How can i call wps layer for creating mbtiles?

Please refer this link for my question

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/mbtiles/output.html

Answer (score 1):

I reached this question while trying to achieve just the same output as @renjith

So, here's what I did to generate MBTiles using GeoServer 2.19.4

**Steps:**

- Enable GDAL native libs on GeoServer by installing GDAL plugin, refer to this link: [GeoServer-gdal](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html)
- Enable WPS on GeoServer by installing WPS plugin, refer to this link: [GeoServer-WPS](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wps/install.html)
- Enable MBTiles read/write on GeoServer by installing MBTiles source/plugin, refer to this link: [GeoServer-MBTiles](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/mbtiles/installing.html)

> Make sure to match plugins versions with your GeoServer instance version!
>
> After successful installation of the above requirements, you should be able to generate MBTiles of your datasource.

**Using WPS request to your server**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0"
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
    xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0"
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
    <ows:Identifier>gs:MBTiles</ows:Identifier>
    <wps:DataInputs>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>layers</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Data>
                <wps:LiteralData>layerName</wps:LiteralData>
            </wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>format</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Data>
                <wps:LiteralData>imageFormat</wps:LiteralData>
            </wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>boundingbox</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Data>
                <wps:BoundingBoxData crs="layerCRS" dimensions="2">
                    <ows:LowerCorner>MinX MinY</ows:LowerCorner>
                    <ows:UpperCorner>MaxX MaxY</ows:UpperCorner>
                </wps:BoundingBoxData>
            </wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>filename</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Data>
                <wps:LiteralData>fileName</wps:LiteralData>
            </wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>minZoom</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Data>
                <wps:LiteralData>minZoom</wps:LiteralData>
            </wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>maxZoom</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Data>
                <wps:LiteralData>maxZoom</wps:LiteralData>
            </wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
    </wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:ResponseForm>
        <wps:RawDataOutput>
            <ows:Identifier>outputFormat</ows:Identifier>
        </wps:RawDataOutput>
    </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

**Make sure to replace each input to match your needs!**

- layerName ==> workspace:layer
- imageFormat ==> png or jpeg
- MinX MinY ==> Space separated values
- MaxX MaxY ==> Space separated values
- fileName ==> Output file name
- minZoom ==> Minimum zoom level inclusive
- maxZoom ==> Maximum zoom level exclusive (If 20 is the value, only 19 zoom levels will be generated)
- outputFormat ==> mbtiles

This request may require basic authentication if map services are protected, and will return a URL of available generated file to be downloaded!