# How to create Mbtiles using WPS or WMS process

Tags: geoserver, mbtiles, wps

I am trying to create mbtiles using WMS but its only generating tiles for 5 zoom levels. how can I increase the zoom levels. i tried below url but was unsuccessful. URL: [https:///geoserver3/GEOSPATIAL/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=&styles=&BBOX=-0.381811,52.256711,0.026260,52.429751&format=mbtiles&width=768&height=652&srs=EPSG:3857&format_options=minZoom:6;maxZoom:23](https://%3Cserver%3E/geoserver3/GEOSPATIAL/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=%3Clayers%3E&styles=&BBOX=-0.381811,52.256711,0.026260,52.429751&format=mbtiles&width=768&height=652&srs=EPSG:3857&format_options=minZoom:6;maxZoom:23) .

I have seen in the documentation that we can create mbtiles using WPS service. Pls give me a sample URL for the same.

Comment: what happened when you were unsuccessful? was there an error in the log? do you know how big zoomlevel:23 is?

Comment: Hi iant, there is no error in the logs and the mbtiles are generated with zoom levels 10-14 even when I give "format_options".

Comment: I've answered a similar question, please refer to this link: [WPS MBTiles generation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71372427/9851488)